# How to get back to the last commit after making some changes?

Tags: git, commit

I've made a couple of changes on my local files but I have not commit or added any of them. I want to go back to my previous commit before this recent changes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git reset --hard
```

will remove those changes.

However, just in case, I would add them

```
git add -A
```

and then stash them

```
git stash
```

Just in case you regret your decision. The last 2 commands can be shortened to:

```
git stash -u
```

Answer (score 1):

**git checkout** might do the job for you. You should be able to do something like:

> git checkout FILE_TO_REVERT

Answer (score 1):

try "git checkout -- files_to_revert
"